# SoftLayer Portable Storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When trying to attach a second Portable Storage to the VSI I receive

> SoftLayer_Exception_Virtual_Guest_MaxPortableVolumes - Unable to attach portable volume. The destination guest has reached the maximum number of allowed disks.

Is this a SoftLayer limitation to allow only single Portable Volume to be connected to the instance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. It depends on the server that you ordered. Some virtual servers only allow 2 disks, others allow 5 or more. You can see the max capacity of your sever in control portal by clicking on "modify configuration" and in the disks section you will see the maximum amount of disk allowed for that server. Also you can see that when you order a new server.

Regards